# convergence of a sequence of continuous nonnegative functions(TIFR GS 2014)

Tags: real-analysis

let $f_n(x)$, for $n \ge 1$, be a sequence of continuous nonnegative functions on [0,1] such that 
     $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{o}^{1} f_n(x)=0$.

Which of the following statements is always correct?

A. $f_n \to 0 $ uniformly on [0,1]

B. $f_n$ may not converge uniformly but converges to $0$ pointwise

C. $f_n$ will converge pointwise and the limit may be nonzero

D. $f_n$ is not guaranteed to have a pointwise limit

i know for sure that A is not true.

Comment: Nice... May be you should ask 4th and 21st :P

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f_n$ to be given such that $f_n(1/2) = n$, and $f_n$ is supported on $(1/2-1/2n^2, 1/2+1/2n^2)$, and $f_n(x) \leq n$ for all $x$. (Think of an isosceles triangle whose apex is at $1/2$). Hence,
$$
\int_0^1 f_n \leq n\frac{1}{n^2} \to 0
$$
but $f_n(1/2)$ does not converge to any real number.

So $D$ is true.